# Error with Script for Dynamically running command

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, shell

I have thousands of database tables in the format similar to below

D_F1
D_FA1
D_FC1
D_FCM1
D_FM1
D_FS1

D_F2
D_FA2
D_FC2
D_FCM2
D_FM2
D_FS2
......

I am writing a shell script to execute some postgres commands that will vacuum the tables.
This is the below command that I am trying to execute

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U dirt -d dirtdb -w -o /tables_list.txt -t -c ' select table_name
                                        from information_schema.tables
                                        where table_schema = 'public'
                                        and table_name ilike 'd\_f%'
                                        order by pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name));'
```

I believe there is an error near order by

```
'd\_f%' order by
```

As I keep getting errors "error near oder"

If i take everything inside the quotes the query runs fine inside of postgres

```
select table_name
                                        from information_schema.tables
                                        where table_schema = 'public'
                                        and table_name ilike 'd\_f%'
                                        order by pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name));
```

Also, i can obviously log in with the ' psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U dirt -d dirtdb ' also.

My question is would someone tell me what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: you may have to escape the simple quotes ' in your sql statement

Comment: In bash, a literal single quot cannot be enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have error because you use `'` (single quote) after the `-c` flag and with statement. Change the single quote after the `-c` to double quote (`"`).